# How to group input values in a form when being submitted?

Tags: html, arrays

I have input values dynamically generated via JS and upon submitting the form, I would like the values to be grouped somehow but fail to see a way to do it.  The reason why I need them to be grouped is when I retrieve the data, it will be easier to loop through.

Consider this HTML:

```
<div class="column one">
     <div class="module">
         <input type="hidden" name="module1[order][]" value="1" />
         <input type="hidden" name="module1[column][]" value="1" />
     </div>

     <div class="module">
         <input type="hidden" name="module5[order][]" value="2" />
         <input type="hidden" name="module5[column][]" value="1" />
     </div>
</div>

<div class="column two">
     <div class="module">
         <input type="hidden" name="module2[order][]" value="1" />
         <input type="hidden" name="module2[column][]" value="2" />
     </div>

     <div class="module">
         <input type="hidden" name="module1[order][]" value="2" />
         <input type="hidden" name="module1[column][]" value="2" />
     </div>
</div>
```

So from the HTML you can see that each module type belongs to a column and each column can have multiple modules of different types.  And in the module there are two input values each holding the data corresponding to the column and position in the DOM.

So when this is submitted currently the array would group all the columns together and group all the order values together.  This would make it very hard for me to get the data when displaying the form again.

I am trying to group the input values by modules instead of the values inside the modules.

Please let me know if I need to explain further as I know this could be confusing to read.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your JS please?

Comment: @Derek - JS is just using the jQuery Draggable/Droppable and Sortable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:
If you change the actual order of the DOM elements, the order of them being submitted also changes. If jQuery changes this order I would have elements like this:

```
div class="column one">
     <div class="module">
         <input type="hidden" name="modules[3][type]" value="1" />
         <input type="hidden" name="modules[3][content]" value="fasdf" />
     </div>

     <div class="module">
         <input type="hidden" name="modules[1][type]" value="2" />
         <input type="hidden" name="modules[1][content]" value="image" />

     </div>
</div>

<div class="column two">
     <div class="module">
         <input type="hidden" name="modules[2][type]" value="1" />
         <input type="hidden" name="modules[2][content]" value="heading" />
     </div>

     <div class="module">
         <input type="hidden" name="modules[0][type]" value="2" />
         <input type="hidden" name="modules[0][content]" value="what ever" />
     </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, that PHP takes the index for sorting the array which is okay and normal. This would be the result:

```
array(4) {
   [3]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(1) "1" ["content"]=> string(5) "fasdf" }
   [2]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(1) "1" ["content"]=> string(7) "heading" }
   [1]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(1) "2" ["content"]=> string(5) "image" }
   [0]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(1) "2" ["content"]=> string(9) "what ever" }
}
```

There are two ways to fix this. One would be to add a little code to the dragging function (if this is possible) or you do something like this before sending the form (jQuery):

```
function check() {
   alert("he");
   $i = 0;
   $(".module").each(function(){
      $(this).find("input[name*='type']").attr("name", "modules["+$i+"][type]"); //*= means like
      $(this).find("input[name*='content']").attr("name", "modules["+$i+"][content]");
      $i++;
   });
   return true;
}
```

This will change the indexes before submitting the form. How I get this al:

```
array(4) {
   [0]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(1) "1" ["content"]=> string(5) "fasdf" }
   [1]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(1) "2" ["content"]=> string(5) "image" }
   [2]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(1) "1" ["content"]=> string(7) "heading" }
   [3]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(1) "2" ["content"]=> string(9) "what ever" }
}
```

Is this a data structure you can work with?

Comment: No because if you did that, you would essentially have module1 => order and another module1 => column.  But I want both order and column to be under module 1.  So the top level should have 4 array elements according to the example above like module1, module5, module2, and module1 and each of these will contain order, column...

Comment: Hmmm...Maybe it would be easier if I explain what I am trying to do instead of asking for a specific outcome because it is likely my needs is not the best way to approach it.  So my app is drag and drop interface which allows users to drag "modules" such as text box, image box so they can build the page they want to display.  On top of that they can reorder the position for example they can put image box on top of text box and vice versa.  This is all done with jQuery sortable, draggable and droppable.  So once they save their settings, I need a way to handle this data and output it.